# Dejo de realizar una operacion una funcion

Tags: c++

ayer estaba realizando un programa y ya estaba terminado

Realize pruebas y todo iba correcto, a la hora de implementar un menu el programa corria correctamente de no ser por una operacion

La desviacion me marca 0 y ayer todo iba bien la calculaba correctamente

```
float VARIANZA(DATOS &objdatos){
  float varianza = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < objdatos.N; i++) {
    varianza += pow((objdatos.datos[i] - MEDIA(objdatos)), 2.0);
  }
  return varianza / (objdatos.N -1);
}

float DESVIACION(DATOS &objdatos){
  float varianza = 0;
  if(varianza == 0){
    float varianza = VARIANZA(objdatos);
  }
  return sqrt(varianza);
}
```

Nota: Con la varianza no hay ningun problema, es solo con el tema de la desviacion

Comment: Borra el if y reemplaza la línea de arriba por `float varianza = VARIANZA(objdatos);`

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta al evaluar la condicional,  `if(varianza == 0){}` porque una linea antes estas declarando tu variable en 0 `float varianza = 0;` por tanto siempre entrada a dicha condición por lo que esta demás, Ademas cuando entra a la condición estas volviendo a dar el tipo de variable a la variable ya creada. te recomiendo usar un código como este

```
float DESVIACION(DATOS &objdatos){
  float varianza = VARIANZA(objdatos);
  return sqrt(varianza);
}
```